# How to apply styles to the div created by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created two divs using the javascript appendChild. I want to apply styles to those div, but the styles aren't working. Here is the JavaScript code. (I want to apply styles in the CSS file only, not using JavaScript.)

```
function list(){
for(var i=0;i<questions.length;i++)
{
    var element = document.createElement("test1");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].ques));
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(element);

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    element.appendChild(br);

    var element1 = document.createElement("test2");
    element1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].answers[0].answer));
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(element1);
}
```

}

my CSS code for test1 and test2 is below, which is not working.

```
    #test1{
    text-align: justify;
    //text-justify:inter-word;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
#test2{
    font-size: 130px;
}
```

Comment: which element do you want to apply styles on?

Comment: Do you use jQuery ? Or only core JavaScript ?

Comment: but in provided code you not create _div_ element

Comment: I have only used the javascript (not the JQuery). I want to apply styles on test1 and test2.

Comment: did u attach class to those elements?

Comment: # in css refers to element ID. Where you are mentioning  test1 as ID to an element?

Comment: you want to create `<test1></test1>` and `<test2></test2>`  tags?

Comment: @ajaygaur319, just remove `#` in your css

Comment: @Grundy Thanks but why so?

Comment: @ajaygaur319, i think others already explain it in answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I dont know why you want to create `<test1>` and `<test2>` tags, you can apply style to it by :

```
test1{
    text-align: justify;
    //text-justify:inter-word;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
test2{
    font-size: 130px;
}
```

Instead you can create a div and attach id to those divs:

```
var elem1= document.createElement("div");
elem1.id = "test1";
elem1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].ques));
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(elem1);

var elem2= document.createElement("div");
elem2.id = "test2";
elem2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].ques));
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(elem2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.createElement("test1")` is creating a `<test1>` element in your document.  Presumably you want this to be a `<div>` or `<span>`?  In which case you code should be something like:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = "test1";
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].ques));
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(element);
```

As well as using the correct element, you then need to set the id so the CSS is applied.

Then do the same again for "test2," creating the appropriate element then setting the id on it to 'test2".